# Binary search operations

Tags: c++, binary-search

Here is an array with exactly 15 elements:

1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10   11   12   13   14   15

Suppose that we are doing a binary search for an element. Circle any elements that will be found by examining two or fewer numbers from the array.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

This is a practice problem from my textbook for my C++ course. I am a little confused because looking up answers online and comparing with my own, they are not matching up. Online people are saying the answer is 8, 4, and 12 while I think it is 7, 11, and 3.

Comment: Remember: No zero element

Comment: There are 15 elements. 15/2 = 7, what element is in `arr[7]` (remember, indexing *starts* at **0**, so `arr[0] == 1`, etc.) ?

Answer (score 1):

The middle element of the array is 8, not 7. Then you are left with two subarrays the first of which has 4 as the mid element and the other 12... Not sure how this could be further explained.  There are as many elements to the left of 8 as there are to the right...